# Inverse Laplace Transform partial fraction $\frac{8}{(S+2)^2 (S+2)} + \frac{S}{(S+2)^2} + \frac{5}{(S+2)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?

> Find the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{8}{(S+2)^2 (S+2)} + \frac{S}{(S+2)^2} + \frac{5}{(S+2)^2}$$

Comment: Would it be helpful to write the first denominator as $(S+2)(S+3)$? and then perform partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: @imranfat I've updated my question

Comment: do you mean for it to now be $(s+2)^2(s+2)$ because that is just $(s+2)^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last term, $\displaystyle \frac{5}{(S+2)^2}\to 5te^{-2t}$.

For the second to last term, $\displaystyle \frac{S}{(S+2)^2}=\frac{1}{(S+2)}-\frac{2}{(S+2)^2}\to e^{-2t}-2te^{-2t}$.

For the first term, $\displaystyle \frac{8}{(S+2)^3}\to 4t^2e^{-2t}$.

Add these three terms up to get your answer, $e^{-2t}(4t^2+3t+1)$.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx

Answer (score 1):

$$(1): \frac{8}{(s+2)^2+(s+2)}$$
Now we can say that:
$$(s+2)^2+(s+2)=(s^2+4s+4)+(s+2)=s^2+5s+6=(s+3)(s+2)$$
Which means we can rewrite then use partial fractions:
$$(1)\Rightarrow\frac{8}{(s+3)(s+2)}=\frac{8}{s+2}-\frac{8}{s+3}$$

---

$$(2):\frac{s}{(s+2)^2}=\frac{1}{s+2}-\frac{2}{(s+2)^2}$$

---

$$(3):\frac{5}{(s+2)^2}$$

---

Now we can say that:
$$\frac{8}{(s+2)^2+(s+2)}+\frac{s}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{5}{(s+2)^2}=\frac{8}{s+2}-\frac{8}{s+3}+\frac{1}{s+2}-\frac{2}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{5}{(s+2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{9}{s+2}-\frac{8}{s+3}+\frac{3}{(s+2)^2}$$

---

$$\mathfrak{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{9}{s+2}-\frac{8}{s+3}+\frac{3}{(s+2)^2}\right)=9e^{-2t}-8e^{-3t}+3te^{-2t}=3\left(3+t\right)e^{-2t}-8e^{-3t}$$

Comment: he changed it lol

Comment: I know its a completely different question now, I'm going to leave it like this though because the formatting makes me think it was a mistake